# WSO2 ESB HL7 Transport Acknowledgement issue

Tags: apache-axis, wso2, wso2-esb

WSO2 ESB provides the HL7 transport which is nice option. The transport operates in couple of modes 1) Default mode: auto acknowledge 2) NACK mode: No acknowledgement 3) ACK mode: Custom acknowledgement from the downstream sequence or another HL7 endpoint. These modes are documented http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB451/HL7+Transport. This JIRA tracker also confirms the same information on configuration of modes. https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-954

The issue that I am facing is that the ACK mode which allows for the acknowledgement from downstream application or sequence to be returned back to the application which had initiated the call to WSO2 ESB. I can clearly see in the log that the downstream application or sequence is returning back the acknowledgement and that is getting parsed by the HL7 transport API. However, the application that is waiting for response from WSO2 ESB always gets default acknowledgement only.

When looking into the HL7 transport code, it looks like that the WSO2 code has a defect and its never returning acknowledgement from downstream sequence. Here is the method from the HL7ProcessingContext.java

```
public Message handleHL7Result(MessageContext ctx, Message hl7Msg) throws HL7Exception     
{
    String resultMode = (String) ctx.getProperty(HL7Constants.HL7_RESULT_MODE);
    if (resultMode != null) {
        if (HL7Constants.HL7_RESULT_MODE_ACK.equals(resultMode)) {
            return this.createAck(hl7Msg);
        } else if (HL7Constants.HL7_RESULT_MODE_NACK.equals(resultMode)) {
            String nackMessage = (String) ctx.getProperty(HL7Constants.HL7_NACK_MESSAGE);
            if (nackMessage == null) {
                nackMessage = "";
            }
            return this.createNack(hl7Msg, nackMessage);
        }
    } else if (this.isAutoAck()) {
        return this.createAck(hl7Msg);
    }
    return this.createNack(hl7Msg, "Application Error: ACK/NACK was not explicitely returned");
}
```

If I am not mistaken, this code needs to be altered as shown below

```
***** Original Code from above****
if (HL7Constants.HL7_RESULT_MODE_ACK.equals(resultMode)) {
            return this.createAck(hl7Msg);
}

***** Revised code *****
if (HL7Constants.HL7_RESULT_MODE_ACK.equals(resultMode)) {
    OMElement omElement = msgCtx.getEnvelope().getBody().getFirstElement().getFirstElement();
    String xmlFormat = omElement.toString();
    Message message = this.xmlParser.parse(xmlFormat);
    return message;
}
```

Could someone confirm this fix?

Answer (score 1):

From version ESB 4.7.0 onwards you can use `HL7_APPLICATION_ACK` property in the hl7 in sequence to wait for the back-end application's response.

```
<property description="HL7_APPLICATION_ACK" name="HL7_APPLICATION_ACK" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="true"/>
```

with parameter `AutoAck` to false in the hl7 proxy

`<parameter name="transport.hl7.AutoAck">false</parameter>`

Answer (score 0):

The existing code is actually correct, if you take a closer a look at the JIRA issue, it has mentioned how the feature should be used. So basically, the user himself does not have to create the XML representation of the ACK HL7 message, this is automatically done when he sets a Axis2 scope message property called "HL7_RESULT_MODE", to either say to ACK or NACK. So basically with that functionality, the downstream application/sequence has the option to ACK or NACK by suitably setting the message property value. Hope this clears the issue.

Cheers,
Anjana.

Comment: I have transport.hl7.AutoAck=false and HL7_RESULT_MODE=ACK. So I am expecting ack from downstream application to be returned back to the user. The user still gets default ack, while WSO2 receives ack from the downstream app and logs it through log mediator and I get exception on console indicating the downstream ack could not be returned to the user as I didn't specify EPR in my send mediator of out sequence. How do I address this? If you can give me a proxy service xml example which shows direct proxy of downstream HL7 app with true ack being returned to the user then that would be great help

Comment: Hi .. I think I just understood your requirement .. you want the HL7 ACK message returned from an external application to be returned from the proxy service .. we do not support that at the moment .. it is the responsibility of the sequence to signal the ESB on how to create a suitable message and response, either an ACK or NACK. So for the moment, what you can do is, check the message returned from the downstream application to see whether it is an ACK or NACK and set the message context appropriately to let the ESB response with the correct message.

Comment: Also, to satisfy your requirement properly, basically which is to support just pass through HL7 messages using the ESB, the code that needs to be changed is, to put an "else" block to the outer most if/else statements that is there in the method, and put similar type of code you mentioned. So with this, basically the last statement saying "Application Error, ACK/NACK to mentioned" would be removed. Can you please create an issue for this as an improvement, so we can check this and fix this properly.

Comment: Posting a defect requires login which I dont have for WSO2 JIRA. How do I get that?

Also, we like to create a patch for the HL7 transport and return true acknowledgement to the ESB client. How do we tell Axis.receive() that it should use the HL7 EPR to return response back? Or may be how do we tell Axis.receive() that we like it to invoke a specific call back handler. Can you point us in the direction or example which can lead us in accomplishing this task?

Comment: Hi, to create a JIRA, you need to have an account in wso2.org, you can simply go there and register yourself as an user. Please do so, and explain your issue there, and as I said earlier, you can still fulfill your requirement for now, by doing a manual intervention of the result from your HL7 call from the ESB sequence and setting the proper property to send by the ACK/NACK.